# Hidden fields, auto assign values in django

Tags: python, django

I am still a newbie on django and Python. This is also my first question. I am trying to create a hidden field and auto assign a value to the hidden field. It can be either in the views or in the templates. I have a field "kind" that needs to be hidden. Also I need to assign a value to it depending on different views/templates so it populates the database.

**This is my class view:**

```
class Monthlypage(CreateView):
    template_name = 'monthly.html'
    model = models.Lead
    form = forms.LeadForm()
    fields = ['name','email','tel','kind']
```

**This is my model form:**

```
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kind = models.Lead.kind
    class Meta:
        model = models.Lead
        kind = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
        fields = ['name','email','tel','kind']
```

**This is my model:**

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=265)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=265)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('registrations')
```

**This is my template:**

```
<form class=""  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="hidden" name="kind" value="{{ form.kind.monthly }}" />
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
```

I have tried many options and spend 2 days using different solutions. But no matter what I do I can't seem to populate the kind field in the database.

Comment: Not the solution, but you don't need to declare the fields both in the view an in the model form, better use the last one. Also if you use all the fields, you could do this this way `fields ='__all__'`.

Comment: hi, you just posted an answer but it disappeared, did you remove it?

Comment: Yes, I think it was a bad answer when I read your code better.

Comment: ok, cool when I don't declare fields in both view and model I get errors. I am aware of the __all__ option, but I tried to not call the hidden field, If i do it shows up in the browser.

Comment: why do you have kind declared in meta?

Comment: to create a hidden field, where should it be?

Comment: Got it... thank for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! Yeah! Please let me know if there is maybe a better or more correct solution!

**This is my class View:**

```
class Monthlypage(CreateView):
    template_name = 'monthly.html'
    model = models.Lead
    form_class = forms.LeadForm
```

**This is my model form:**

```
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Lead
        fields = ['name','email','tel','kind']
        widgets = {
        'kind':forms.HiddenInput()

        }
```

**This is my model:**

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=265)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=265)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('registrations')
```

**This is my template:**

```
<form class=""  method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% bootstrap_form form %}
<input type="hidden" name="kind" value="monthly">
<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
```

Finally after 2 days of struggling, I hope this can help someone else out!